# SQL Insert into proper column ID

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, syntax

fast question. I have SQL database with a table named `answers`.

This table contains column `id,answer_1,answer_2 etc.`

At first, when I start my app, it generates a random number and Inserts it to table `answers` as `student_id`.

Then the student is answering the questions, and after each answer, I would like to insert ones answer to the base.

In pseudo-code I would like to make something like this:

```
INSERT INTO answers (answer_1) VALUES ("blah blab") WHERE student_id=xxx
```

Is it a possible way to make something like this?

Comment: Well, your "pseudo-code" is actual working SQL for the most part. What about it is not working the way you want it to. Your question is quite ambiguous. And I wouldn't use randomly generated numbers. Use a sequence, or your DBMS equivalent, otherwise you will end up with clashing `student_id` values.

Comment: Please forget about indexed columns like `answer1, answer2`, etc.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Actualy UPDATE function works :)

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers. (I.e. objects with _strange_names, e.g. `"Odd Column name...?"`.) Use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'blah blab'`.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are saying, a record will already exist for the student, so to insert the answers you'd need to use UPDATE:

```
UPDATE [answers] SET [answer_1] = 'blah blab' WHERE [student_id] = xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two conditions:

- If you want to update the value, the it is simple,use the following code:

  UPDATE [answers]
   SET [answer_1] = 'blah blab'
   WHERE [student_id] = xxx;

or if you want the system to update the records by itself, then clear your question, edit it or ask a new question.